# How to join two lists of parent/child objects using LINQ while grouping on child key

Tags: c#, linq

I want to create a list of `CustomerOrder` and group the `quantity` by `item_id`. The code nearly works, but it doesn't group on `item_id`.

I also think there is something wrong in terms of performance/memory usage. It works when the total list size is ~1000 but when it gets upto ~30,000 it has memory issues.

I suspect the issue is with "select new Customer". I probably shouldn't be using `ToList()`, I couldn't do it as IEnumerable. 
I thought that `GroupJoin` would be the way to go, but I can't get that to work either. The example I found using group join had a "foreign key" value in the child table, I don't have that.

```
public class CustomerOrder
{
    public int order_id { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public int item_id { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<CustomerOrder> list1 = new List<CustomerOrder>()
        {new CustomerOrder{order_id = 1, OrderLines = new List<OrderLine>()
        {new OrderLine()
        {item_id = 123, quantity = 2}, new OrderLine()
        {item_id = 456, quantity = 3}}}};

        List<CustomerOrder> list2 = new List<CustomerOrder>()
        {new CustomerOrder{order_id = 1, OrderLines = new List<OrderLine>()
        {new OrderLine()
        {item_id = 456, quantity = 2}, new OrderLine()
        {item_id = 789, quantity = 3}}}};

        var orderdetails =
            from g in list1.Concat(list2).GroupBy(x => x.order_id) select new CustomerOrder { order_id = g.Key, OrderLines = g.SelectMany(x => x.OrderLines).ToList() };

        foreach (var item in orderdetails)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.order_id);
            foreach (var line in item.OrderLines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", line.item_id, line.quantity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The current output is:

```
1
123 2
456 3
456 2
789 3
```

My desired output is:

```
1
123 2
456 5
789 3
```

Each list should be unique based on `order_id` but there would be overlap in terms of `order_lines`. One list will almost always be significantly larger than the other. The current ratio is 29,500:500 on a 30K sample.

Comment: Remove foreach(var line ....) and replace with :  Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.key, item.OrderLines.Sum(x => x.quantity));

Comment: I'd highly recommend reading "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)", especially the "Spelling, grammar and formatting" section. SO isn't a message board or forum, it's more like an online reference book and grammar matters. Also, I highly recommend reading "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)". It's long but is full superb advice.

Comment: Yeah, you really should fix that formatting, but kudos for posting a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group your `OrderLines` too:

```
var orderdetails =
    from g in list1.Concat(list2).GroupBy(x => x.order_id) 
    select new CustomerOrder 
    { 
        order_id = g.Key,
        OrderLines = g
            .SelectMany(x => x.OrderLines)
            .GroupBy(ol => ol.item_id)
            .Select(g => new OrderLine 
            {
                item_id = g.Key, quantity = g.Sum(gg => gg.quantity)
            })
            .ToList() 
    };
```

As for performance to handle 30k+ entries (especially if first collection is guaranteed to have unique orders) I think better would be create a dictionary from  the first collection, switching to `for`/`foreach` loop on the second collection and in it add/update elements in dictionary (including the child objects) and not create new ones.

Or at least try:

```
var orderdetails =  list1
    .Concat(list2)
    .GroupBy(x => x.order_id)
    .Select(g => 
    {
        // may be better to materialize group, 
        // and use it for First and SelectMany
        var order = g.First();
        order.OrderLines = g
            .SelectMany(og => og.OrderLines)
            .GroupBy(ol => ol.item_id)
            .Select(olg => 
            {
                var line = olg.First();
                line.quantity = olg.Sum(ol => ol.quantity);
                return line;
            })
            .ToList();
        return order;
    })
```

Comment: Guru Stron i will give that example a try.
i have realised i can qualify the data a bit better and i will update the question.
each list will be unique by order_id but there will be some overlap between lists.
one list will be almost certainly be significantly larger than the other, currently in the order of magnitude of 29,500:500 based on a 30K sample. that wont always be the case but the same list will almost always be larger than the other.
i will explore dictionary option as well.